# Unnest all nested rows (GA4/BigQuery)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-analytics, unnest

I need to unnest all event_params for all events coming from GA4 that are stored in nested table in  BigQuery.

What I need to achieve is to be able to extract all events with all of their event_params without specifying the names for each of them and their data types, simply fully unnest all records.

Writing an unnest query for each event_param will not work as new ones will constantly be added.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: is this question programming related?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use some sort of script in order to dynamically extract all available params into columns.
Either generate a list of available params in an SQL Statement Script, and then iterate over that list to generate the columns, or use dbt scripts to perform the same.

See examples here:

[Explanations about SQL Procedural Language in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language)

[dbtCore Jinja & Loops](https://docs.getdbt.com/guides/using-jinja?step=3)

OR - you can use the existing ga4 dbt package by Velir, available here:

[ga4 dbt package by Velir](https://hub.getdbt.com/Velir/ga4/latest/)